# How to take input file into foreach loop

Tags: perl

Input file (i.e happy.txt generated from happy)

```
NAME     PEND RUN SUSP JLIM JLIMR   RATE   HAPPY
akawle   8    20  0    100  20:100  67980  71%
akumar6  16   0   0    100  100     0      0%
apatil2  2    4   0    100  10:100  20398  67%
ashetty  0    3   0    100  40:100  9725   100%
bdash    2    0   0    100  100     0      0%
```

#### code

```
gen_ls_data();

sub gen_ls_data{

    my($lines) = @_;
    my $header_found = 0;
    my @headers = ();
    my $row_count = 0;
    my %row_data = ();

    $lines = `happy`;
    system("happy > happy.txt");

    my $filename = 'happy.txt';
    open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    print $fh $lines ;
    close $fh;

    foreach (split("\n",$lines)) {
        if (/NAME\s*PEND/) {
        $header_found = 1;      
        @headers =split;
        next;
    }

    if ( $header_found == 0 ) { }
    else {

        if (/^\s*$/) {
            $header_found=0;
            next; 
        }

        $row_data{$row_count++} = $_;
    }
}
```

How can I pass the `happy.txt` directly into the `foreach` loop without passing the `$lines` variables Linux command?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the lines once you've loaded them into a perl data structure? I'm having trouble following.

Comment: i had used happy command and stored the command output into happy.txt.Then to read the file used the read operations.To split the contents inside forach loop i had used the linux command stored variables(i.e $lines).Now i want to use the happy.txt file directly inside foreach loop.Is it possible to modify my code@GregoryNisbet

Comment: I'm confused - you open `$filename` for reading (`'<'`), and then you print to it? I'm not following your intentions here at all.

Comment: Me too, confused. (1) You receive `$lines` from arguments. (2) But you _also_ get `$lines` as output of ```happy``` (3) Then you _also_ open `'happy.txt'` to read those same lines, yet again ... (4) but then you _write to that file_.  If you need `$lines` for `foreach`,  **either** take them as function argument (and don't worry about files),  **or** get them by executing `happy` under backticks, **or** execute `happy` via `system` and redirect them to a file, which you then read.  _One_ of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you simply need `$lines` for processing in the `foreach` loop.

**Either** get them as arguments passed to the function

```
my ($lines) = @_;
# ...
# no need to run "happy" in any way or to deal with files
foreach (split /\n/, $lines) {
    # ...
}
```

**or** get them as output from `happy`

```
# no need for function arguments to contain $lines
my $lines = `happy`;
# no need for system() and reading the file
foreach (split /\n/, $lines) {
    # ...
}
```

**or** run `system` with redirection and *read* from the file

```
my $filename = 'happy.txt';
system ("happy > $filename");
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    # process each line from the file
}
```

In this case you can nicely read line by line, instead of having `$lines` and `split`-ing it.

You can do that with backticks (the [qx operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)) as well,

```
my @lines = `happy`;
```

since in the *list context* it returns the *list* of lines from output, not the scalar with all of them.

---

Note that you should add error checking for all calls that go out to the system (and not only for that!). The [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) returns *zero* if it ran fine, so you normally do something like

```
system(...) == 0 or die "Can't fork: $!";
```

while `qx` on error returns `undef` in scalar context or empty list in list context, so these can be used for an initial check for problems.

They both also set the [$? variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) which you can interrogate for details, see the link and the links for `system` and `qx`. Note that this firstly concerns *their* operation, and not necessarily how well the command that they execute itself did.

Comment: Great explanation.It helps me@zdim